# A Good Spring 3.1's annotation tutorial

Tags: hibernate, spring

I want to learn the Spring 3.1's annotations. For that I have read several blog posts of [Spring Source Blog](http://blogs.springsource.com), now I have the basic idea of all the new Spring features i.e @Cacheable, @Profile, no Web.xml approach etc.

Now I want to develop a small sample application using these annotations but the problem is I am not able to configure my project properly, Since this is my first project using **"least or no XML please!!"** approach, I have missed something while configuring. I am using Hibernate 3.6.8 along with Spring 3.1 inside NetBeans 7.1 (maven 3.0.3).

I am trying to find out **a good tutorial for Java (annotation) Based configuration of Spring & hibernate**, most of the answers at SO are somewhat outdated. So had to post this question **please excuse me if you find it a duplicate one!!!**

**Please suggest a good tutorial for Spring annotations based configuration or suggest me what might have been wrong in my project...**

Comment: Perhaps you should share your configuration and the error you get.

Comment: I just found a superb one: http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.nl/2012/01/spring-31-mvc-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the [Spring Reference Manual](http://www.springsource.org/spring-core#documentation) where everything is well explained.

28.3 @Caceable annotation

@Profile is currently linked to [Spring Source Team Blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)

Instead of Hibernate annotations you should use the JPA annotations where possible.

[JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html)